# Which native or browser method is used to paint ui from virtual dom to real dom in react?

Tags: reactjs

I read that once render is called, UI component are added into real DOM after comparing virtual DOM.

Just wanted to know which method is used by React to paint/add/update the UI on real DOM?

Comment: What do you mean which method?

Comment: You'll find all the info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: I mean method like appendChild as some method must be called to add UI to real DOM from VDOM which holds JSON representation